# Building Hadoop with Maven error: generate-version-annotation

Tags: eclipse, maven, hive

I'm trying to build the `hive` branch `0.13` using Maven on windows. I got the project with svn. But when I tried `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Phadoop-1`，I'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Hive Common ....................................... FAILURE [0.099s]
[INFO] Hive Serde ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Metastore .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Query Language ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Service ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive JDBC ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Beeline ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive CLI .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Contrib ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HBase Handler ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog Core ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog Pig Adapter ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog Server Extensions ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog Webhcat Java Client ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog Webhcat ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HCatalog HBase Storage Handler ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive HWI .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive ODBC ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Shims Aggregator ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive TestUtils .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hive Packaging .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.555s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 03 14:55:25 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/75M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generate-version-annotation) on project hive-common: An Ant BuildException haxception: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common"): CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">... @ 4:46 in D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generate-version-annotation)ception has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common"): CreateProcesaround Ant part ...<exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">... @ 4:46 in D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in d.6\hive-0.13\common"): CreateProcess error=2, ?????????around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">... @ 4:46 in D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common\target\antrun\build-main.xml:4: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in direhive-0.13\common"): CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:675)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse 8.6\hive-0.13\common"): CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 39 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

I googled, but couldn't resolve this problem,  Could someone give me a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Try googling more... first hit: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-dev/201310.mbox/%3CJIRA.12675107.1382470208827.106435.1382476427474@arcas%3E

Comment: @MaxLeske that is a very different error. CreateProcess succeeded but bash.exe returned errorcode 1. Don't jump to conclusions...

Comment: Now I encountered this problem～ CreateProcess succeeded but bash.exe returned errorcode 1

Answer (score 1):

That's because saveVersion.sh can not execute command

```
mkdir -p $src_dir/gen/org/apache/hive/common
cat << EOF | \
  sed -e "s/VERSION/$version/" -e "s/SHORTVERSION/$shortversion/" \
      -e "s/USER/$user/" -e "s/DATE/$date/" \
      -e "s|URL|$url|" -e "s/REV/$revision/" \
      -e "s|BRANCH|$branch|" -e "s/SRCCHECKSUM/$srcChecksum/" \
      > $src_dir/gen/org/apache/hive/common/package-info.java
```

I Modify to

```
mkdir -p '$src_dir/gen/org/apache/hive/common'
cat << EOF | \
  sed -e "s/VERSION/$version/" -e "s/SHORTVERSION/$shortversion/" \
      -e "s/USER/$user/" -e "s/DATE/$date/" \
      -e "s|URL|$url|" -e "s/REV/$revision/" \
      -e "s|BRANCH|$branch|" -e "s/SRCCHECKSUM/$srcChecksum/" \
      > '$src_dir/gen/org/apache/hive/common/package-info.java'
```

Then resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building fine, but from an environment where [cygwin's](http://www.cygwin.com/) bash.exe (alone with other cygwin tools) are in the path.

Comment: use mvn orders in cygwin window？  or  just configure cygwin environment on windows operation？

Comment: Simply have `<installpath>cygwin1-7\bin` in the path so that CreateProcess bash succeeds. I'm not running with a cygwin window.

Comment: Btw, you're going to have to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Phadoop-1 -DskipTests` to get the correct Eclipse projects, then add these projects to your workspace (Import/Exiting Projects), modify the `M2_REPO` classpath variable (global pref, not per project) to point to your Maven repo (c:\Users\<you>\.m2\repository) and then you'll be able to build from Eclipse too, debug, run JUnits etc.

Comment: I installed cygwin and add D:\IDE\cygwin\bin in the path; but it report another error [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generate-version-annotation) on project hive-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1